# The fastest connection between Gatwick & Heathrow?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, lhr, lgw

I arrive in Gatwick, south terminal on January 8 at 10:10am and I have exactly 3 hours to my next connection flight to Heathrow Airport terminal 3. Is this connection possible? What is the safest and best way of transportation to Heathrow?

Comment: Do you have checked baggage and is this is an international arrival

Comment: I will try to travel only with carry on to reduce time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd have to be extremely lucky to make this and I strongly recommend against this.

Some public options are here https://www.heathrow.com/transport-and-directions/travel-between-airports

Basically you can take a direct bus or go through London using the Gatwick Express to Victoria, tube to Paddington and Heathrow Express to Heathrow. The trains are most predictable the buses are subject to traffic which can be bad at this time of day. Google maps give the drive time anywhere between 45 minutes and 1 and a half hours.

Your best bet would probably be a taxi or a private car hire, but this would be very expensive and still no guarantee.

If you have checked luggage and/or need to go through immigration, this is probably a non-starter.

**Edit:**

I checked the national express schedule. If you can make the 10:40am bus from Gatwick and traffic is not too bad, you get into Heathrow at 12:05. IF you already have checked in and your boarding pass in hand and no checked luggage, you may have a chance of making it, but it is very risky. You need to check the check-in and boarding cutoff time for your departing flight

Comment: Why are they selling this connection as possible? The airline won't change my ticket unless I'm paying double than I already paid for the entire flight. if I lose the flight I will have to purchase new ticket... are there any private transportation? How much can it be for a car?

Comment: Did you buy this directly from the airline or from an aggregator like kiwi.com ?

Comment: It looks like British Airways quotes a minimum connection time of 3 hours and recommends using the National Express bus. See https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/airport-information/flight-connections Seems awfully tight to me

Comment: Purchased through Just Fly...which charges huge fees to change the flight. I never knew I was changing airports as all I saw there was 3 hours layover. This is done intentionally but I have to find a solution. The computer doesn't take in consideration traffic or reality

Comment: @ibcoAccounting: you may want to ask jusfly and the ariline (independently) what happens if you miss the connection. If it's on a single ticket, typically the airline will rebook you for free on the next flight unless you are "at fault". In this case the definition of "at fault" is murky